# How to uninstall turnserver-1.8.2.0?

Tags: linux, centos, makefile, webrtc, rfc5766turnserver

After extracting the rfc5766-turnserver-1.8.2.0.tar.gz, I am unable to find the uninstall script. The extracted directory contains these files and folders:

```
AUTHORS  bin  build  ChangeLog  configure  docs  doxygen.conf  examples  include  INSTALL  lib  LICENSE  Makefile  Makefile.in  make-man.sh  man  NOTE  README.turnadmin  README.turnserver  README.turnutils  src  STATUS  TODO  turndb  wiki
```

I have configured it by `./configure` followed by `make` and `make install`. Everything worked fine. Now I want to uninstall this. But I don't find any way. How to resolve this ? I am using CentOS 6.5

Comment: Did you try `make uninstall`?

Comment: find and remove all the libraries, start up scripts, and binary files...

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, with this method of installation, there is no such thing as an uninstall script (!)
There isn't even a reliable way to list all installed files.

However, usually, the `Makefile` has a variable such as `$DESTDIR` that represents the top level directory under which everything is installed.  So often you can do something like

```
make DESTDIR=/tmp/dummydest
```

and then do something like

```
(cd /tmp/dummydest && find . -type f) | (cd /usr/local && xargs -n1 rm)
```

to remove the same files in the location you originally installed them in.

DIsclaimers:

1. *Never* do this blindly, it may go horribly wrong.
2. *Never* tell me I told you to do this.